# expect script unable to fetch server logs into the text file

Tags: bash, expect

I am trying to access remote ssh server from a unix client machine. For this i have used expect script which is calling a bash script to fetch some lines from server log file.

Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f
set pass "password"
set prompt "(%|$|#)"
spawn ssh deployed@172.16.166.111

expect "password:"
send "$pass\r"

expect -re $prompt
send -- "./access_srvr_log.sh\r"

send -- "exit\r"
```

---

code for  access_srvr_log.sh file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect

dir="/home/deployer/Desktop/McKinsey-McKinsey-AdminPanel/log"
tail -n 100 $dir/development.log
echo "hello"
echo >> log.txt
```

i get this error :

```
./access_srvr_log.sh
-bash: ./access_srvr_log.sh: No such file or directory
```

Please help. I have tried lot many changes on the above code and finally reached here.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the script on the server? If not, wont it work if you use `send -- \`cat ./access_srvr_log.sh\` `?

Comment: Do this at a shell prompt: `ssh deployer@ip ls -l access_srvr_log.sh`  -- do you see it?

Comment: Why does your remote shell script have an expect shebang line?

Comment: Thanks Tomas i'll try this in the next go.

Glenn.. in my scenario i have to execute bash script using expect only.
i'll remove the expect from shebang line in bash script in next execution. Thanks!

Comment: You could do without expect and without the remote script if tail is all you need: `ssh host tail -n 100 /home.... >log.txt` with the added benefit of getting the log to your local machine, which I suspect is what actually want.

Comment: Thanks for the help but Nothing worked out as suggested above.
 file is not kept on server

Comment: I haven't reached to any solution from the above suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it down too

```
#!/bin/bash

{
/usr/bin/expect  <<- EOF
    spawn ssh deployer@172.16.144.111 "tail -n 100 /home/deployer/Desktop/McKinsey-McKinsey-AdminPanel/log/development.log"
    expect "password:"
    send "deployer\r"
    expect eof
EOF
} |grep -v  "deployer@172.16.144.111's password:">>  log.txt
```

Comment: Yes i want to run bash script on remote ssh server. But it can't read the 12 th line of code.

Comment: Trying to understand what your asking for. Question 1:  Are you saying you want the bash script running on the remote machine to send t output back to expect program running on the client side? Question 2: do you really want to `echo >> log.txt to append empty lines to the log.txt. Question 3: Or is it that you want to take the last 100 lines of $dir/development.log on the remote machine and append them to log.txt on the local machine?

Comment: 1: Yes 3: yes. please help in this.

Comment: @pranky301 I made the changes to do #1 and #3 as well as added some additional simplifications. Every thing is contained in one script. Please mark if you found this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Friends don't let friends use SSH passwords. It's much less secure.

Use `ssh-copy-id` to copy your public key to the remote server. (It puts the client `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into the server `.ssh/authorized_keys`) Now you can run "ssh deployer@172.16.144.111 ./access_srvr_log.sh", and it won't prompt for a password. That means you no longer need `expect` and all the odd problems that come with it.

In fact, [it's highly recommended that you disable SSH passwords all together](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring).

To make your script even simpler (maintenance-wise) do this:

1) run `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/scriptkey` on your client (don't enter a password).

2) Put the public part of your key (`~/.ssh/scriptkey.pub` on the client) into  `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.  But this time, put `command="/home/deployer/access_srvr_log.sh"` just before your new key. This tells the server to run that command for that key.

3) Now your script doesn't even need to specify the command, just the private key. (i.e. `scp -i ~/.ssh/scriptkey deployer@172.16.144.111` will run the script). This allows the server to change (i.e. move the script, change the script name) without changing the client.  It also means someone stealing your (non-password-protected) key can't log in to the server, but only run your log script.

And there are no guessable passwords laying around in scripts. (You are checking your scripts into version control, right?)